# Как поменять цвет и вид всех меток по результатам поиска в Яндекс Картах?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Как поменять стандартную метку для всей карты https://yadi.sk/i/LYkXUorDYNMXLg чтобы вместо синих - например, зеленые были. Автоматически для всех результатов

Comment: сегодня какой-то шквал вопросов  такого характера про яндекс